# change product image and information by selecting option image in opencart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

I like to change my site like this pic: http://screencast.com/t/4WtB4YpN

[image]

I followed this site:

> http://www.newlook.com/shop/mens/jackets-and-coats/navy-stripe-trim-bomber-jacket-_297715340

I don't understand how to do it. Can somebody help me to sort this problem?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There are lot of plugins for this or similar behavior for OpenCart or you can use some JS plugins (or even pure jQuery) and do it for yourself. You might be interested in googling for *Opencart image change on click* or *jquery change image on click*...

Answer (score 0):

You can get small image src with js and then put it in src attribute of large image

```
var src = $(small_image_id_or_class).attr('src');
$(large_image_id_or_class).attr('src',src);
```